# Android ListView select item and show information about list item

Tags: android, listview

I am very new to Android.

I need to create a list view, where there's a list of items on the left, and clicking on an item opens up a dialog box like thing to show info about the item. Moreover, I want to be able to select these (or check?) items from the list of items, then click on a "Done" button within the same screen to go back to another activity that uses the three selected item.
I've tried reading up on the ListView documentation but so far Android hasn't been so intuitive, which is why I'm really held up.

Here's my current code:

public class PlayerList extends ListActivity {

```
static final String[] PLAYERS = new String[] { "Messi", "Ronaldo", "Drogba", "Wesley"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // no more this
    // setContentView(R.layout.list_fruit);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view2,PLAYERS));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text

            // edit this part to be able to show a new screen with info about the player

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Can you please advise me on how I can 1) create the detailed screen for each item upon a click, 2) be able to check/select items, 3)modify the current code to include 1 & 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the information you can use this code for the dialog box and this can be called by showSettingsAlert(); wherever you want this dialog box to displayed.

```
   public void showSettingsAlert(){
         AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

         // Setting Dialog Title
         alertDialog.setTitle("Title here");

         // Setting Dialog Message
         alertDialog.setMessage("here the information can be display");


         alertDialog.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             dialog.cancel();

             }
         });

         // Showing Alert Message
         alertDialog.show();
     }
```

for the other thing look Contextual Action Mode. these links can be helpful to you

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/